# Idiom's tense when writing a novel in past tense

Tags: idioms, past-tense

If the novel is written in past tense, what tense should the idioms be when they are used by the narrator?

For example, consider the following passage:

> The fight was over. John stood over the prostrated Alan who pleaded for his life.
> Even though it was heart-rending to see it, Bob did not move to help his comrade: you did not bring a knife to a gunfight.

Should it be "you **did** not bring a knife to a gunfight" or "you **do** not bring a knife to a gunfight"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the phrase is a general observation by the narrator, the idiom should be in its present tense form.
`You don't bring a knife to a gunfight.`

If the narrator is making a specific statement about that instance, it could be
`He shouldn't have brought a knife to a gunfight.`

Both statements are about what the narrator thinks should happen, or should have happened, so the form "you did not bring..." doesn't fit, because that would be a factual statement about the past.